# Hierarchy database structure

Tags: database, recursive-query

I am developing a database for a local language which allow user to search the rhyme words. The system I am trying to develop will not only search the rhyme words but also the rhyme words of each of the search items. That can go to n level. To simplify, here is the example:

If I search word 'study' the basic result would set would be be like bloody, buddy but then I also want to search each of these result set to include the rhyme words of each of them. In other words I want to get the list of friends of the friends of the friends of the friends .... till the nth level.

I know I can get this through recursive query but when the database will grow, that query be very slow to respond.

Can anybody suggest some good database table structure which will help me here.

Regards

Comment: have you taken a look at graph databases?  neo4j as one example.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe look at creating a type of "lookup" table with all possible rhyme variations, using a phonetic representation of the sound as your key - that should be a reasonable manageable size, e.g. in your example, you would have the representation of the sound "udy" in your rhyme lookup. Let's call that table "phonetic"

In a 2nd table, have all the words you want to analyse or search on, let's call that table "word"

In a 3rd table, you create your mapping between a word and one or more entries in "phonetic", let's call it "rhyme"

It would take a little more thought to get the lookups set up, but then as the database grew, your performance would scale too, because then you could search for all "rhyme" entries for a "word" record, then find all mappings to the same "phonetic" value in the "rhyme" table.

If you go with the recursive structure, I think you would very quickly find it unable to scale.